# Fire-and-forget Call in Reactive

Tags: reactor

I have to make a call to an API but not  wait for its result. I have a `stream` object. Here's what I am doing:

```
Mono.just(stream).mergeWith(makeCall()).next().subscribe(...);
```

makeCall() takes some time, so what I thought is that `next()` would give me the `stream` object and it would be propogated down the stream.

What's happening instead is that `next()` cancels the subscription after consuming `stream. Hence, no call takes place.

Is there a proper way to make a fire-and-forget call?

Comment: It might be clearer if you gave the types, but why not `makeCall(); Mono.just(stream)...`?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with RxJava and relates to Reactor-Core only. Please make sure you tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov it will keep waiting for the makeCall() to return.

Comment: Then so will your version. Before calling `mergeWith` its argument has to be evaluated. What's the type of `makeCall()`?

Comment: And is it fully synchronous (that is, does it finish the entire call before returning?)

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Yes, it does.